# Is there a simpler way to work with UK date format in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

To work with UK date format, as is my preference, the following code snippet will get me a UK date format (Powershell does not take into account machine locale).

`$UKdate = [datetime]::Parse($req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString(),([Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB')))`

This seems unwieldy, particularly when the language is normally so concise. Is there a better way that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell does take the locale into account, but casting to `[DateTime]` does not.

That is, if you were to run this with a UK culture it'll parse it as a UK date:

```
Get-Date $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
```

Where as this will always choose `en-US`:

```
[DateTime]$req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
```

Chris

Comment: That's correct in fairness. My issue arises if I attempt to do something like: Tee-Object $LogFile "this expires on $UKDate" when it will print it in US format again! So it grabs the date correctly, however if you then embed the variable within a string it reverts to US date format.

Comment: So it does, but that's harder to override because it's simply including a DateTime object in a string. Reproducible with `$ukdate = Get-Date; "$ukdate"`. Note that while I'm saying it's a UK date there it's nothing of the sort, it's a DateTime object. You can work around it by explicitly calling the ToString method on the DateTime. `$ukdate.ToString()`. Not ideal though.

Comment: Thanks. I made a hash of the question as it's a while since I was looking at this. I got around it with: Tee-Object $LogFile "this expires on "  -Append $UKDate. Which isn't ideal....